# reload(sys) cause subsequent executions lose their `Out[n]:` tag

Tags: python, ipython

I just noticed this peculiar behavior relating to interactive use of `ipython` shell. I think the following example is quite straightforward to demonstrate what I mean:

Invoke a fresh `ipython` session; execute the following statements, notice the lost of `Out[n]:` tag after `reload(sys)` statement.

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: 1
Out[2]: 1

In [3]: reload(sys)
<module 'sys' (built-in)>

In [4]: 1
1
```

The version infos are Python 2.7.10 and IPython 2.4.1, Fedora 22.

Is this a bug of CPython and/or IPython? If not, why is this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in ipython's `sys.displayhook`, which differs from the system version. From `help(sys)`:

```
Dynamic objects:

[...]

displayhook -- called to show results in an interactive session
```

When you do `reload(sys)`, it pulls in the system's version of `sys`, not ipython's, so it doesn't have the patched version:

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: print sys.displayhook
<IPython.core.displayhook.DisplayHook object at 0x105bc1dd0>

In [3]: reload(sys)
<module 'sys' (built-in)>

In [4]: print sys.displayhook
<built-in function displayhook>
```

You can see the code for it in [core/displayhook.py](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/displayhook.py) in the ipython codebase. And you can even work around it, if you really care:

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: print sys.displayhook
<IPython.core.displayhook.DisplayHook object at 0x10ba2ddd0>

In [3]: dh = sys.displayhook

In [4]: reload(sys)
<module 'sys' (built-in)>

In [5]: print sys.displayhook
<built-in function displayhook>

In [6]: 2
2

In [7]: sys.displayhook = dh

In [8]: 2
Out[8]: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

IPython uses the [`sys.ps1` value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.ps1) as the input prompt, and *adds* `sys.ps3` for the output. To make displaying `sys.ps3` on output work, [`sys.displayhook`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook) has been set:

> `sys.displayhook` is called on the result of evaluating an *expression* entered in an interactive Python session. The display of these values can be customized by assigning another one-argument function to `sys.displayhook`.

Reloading reset the hook to the default `None`.

Reset it with:

```
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().display_trap.set()
```

This is more convenient than trying to store the `DisplayHook` instance beforehand.